# Results for the two perspectives vs. results of the two perspectives

Tags: prepositions

I usually don't really struggle with prepositions, but there is one instance where I am not sure whether to use "of" or "for".

Take this sentence as an example:

*The results for/of both perspectives are rather similar.*

I feel like "for" is more appropriate, but I am not sure why. Would be great if a native speaker could opine.

To provide a bit more context:

In the ICAAP, which is a regulatory requirement for banks, ([see here if you want to know more](https://www.bafin.de/SharedDocs/Veroeffentlichungen/EN/Fachartikel/2018/fa_bj_1807_Risikotragfaehigkeit_en.html#:%7E:text=Whereas%20the%20normative%20perspective%20primarily,values%20and%20similar%20valuation%20approaches.))

there are two different perspectives/views (Normative and Economic), i.e. two different ways to compute "the numbers". Hence, I usually need to mention whether I am talking about the results for/of the Normative View or the Economic View to make clear what I am talking about.

Thank you!

Comment: I agree that _for_ is better. I'm no economist, but it seems they are not 'results of the perspectives' like 'results of an experiment', but results of calculations using those perspectives.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks for your comment. Yes, the perspectives are more or less frameworks for the calculations.

Comment: I would rather use "[**from** both perspectives](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/from+perspective)".

Comment: I don't understand how a perspective can have a result. If that were clearer from the context, it would be easier to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of particular prepositions in particular situations is often quite subjective. However, saying "the results of X" frequently suggests that the results were produced by X. (Kate Bunting, in a comment, mentions "results of an experiment". We could also talk about the results of a contest, results of a decision, etc.) Therefore, assuming that neither perspective actually produced the results, I agree that "for" seems to work better.

However, I'd probably prefer "according to" over both of those prepositions:

> The results according to both perspectives are rather similar.